# How to enable swagger UI in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, asp.net-core-2.0, aws-api-gateway

I created the serverless application using .Net core and hosted in AWS. I am able to create swagger.json by publishing API documentation under API gateway.

I am looking for the documentation to create swagger UI for those APIs. 
Is any possibility to view the swagger UI in AWS itself.

Comment: Did you find spultuon for this?

Answer (score 11):

I do not think AWS built a swagger UI in one of their services. At least, I am not aware of it.

However, it is possible to easily create a swagger visualization using S3.
There is an article on Medium which explains this well. [1]

Basically, what you need to script is:

- Creation of an S3 bucket with static website hosting
- Downloading the static swagger UI resources from GitHub
- Syncing the resources to the S3 bucket
- Downloading the swagger.json from API Gateway [2]
- Uploading the swagger.json to S3
- Modify index.html to point at your swagger.json

These steps are laid out in detail in the Medium article. [1]

#### References

[1] https://medium.com/nirman-tech-blog/swagger-ui-for-aws-api-gateway-endpoints-a667f25f5a4b
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-export-api.html

Answer (score 1):

You can easily host self-contained swagger-UI web site in S3.

Here is an example: https://iris-fhir-server.s3.amazonaws.com/swagger-ui.html

Github: https://github.com/intersystems-community/Swagger-IRIS-FHIR

It's essentially your OpenAPI yaml or json files plus single HTML page like:

```
<!-- HTML for static distribution bundle build -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Swagger UI</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@3/swagger-ui.css" >
    <style>
      html
      {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }    
      *,
      *:before,
      *:after
      {
        box-sizing: inherit;
      }

      body
      {
        margin:0;
        background: #fafafa;
      }
      .errors-wrapper {
         display: none !IMPORTANT;
      }
    </style>
  </head>    
  <body>
    <div id="swagger-ui"></div>    
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@3/swagger-ui-bundle.js"> </script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@3/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js"> </script>    <script>
    window.onload = function() {          
      // Begin Swagger UI call region
      const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        "dom_id": "#swagger-ui",
        deepLinking: true,
        presets: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
          SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
        ],
        plugins: [
          SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
        ],
        layout: "StandaloneLayout",
        validatorUrl: "https://validator.swagger.io/validator",
        //url: "https://iris-fhir-server.s3.amazonaws.com/openapi/Patient.yml",
        urls: [
          {url: "https://iris-fhir-server.s3.amazonaws.com/openapi/Organization.yml", name: "Organization"},
          {url: "https://iris-fhir-server.s3.amazonaws.com/openapi/Patient.yml", name: "Patient"},
          {url: "https://iris-fhir-server.s3.amazonaws.com/openapi/Practitioner.yml", name: "Practitioner"},
          {url: "https://iris-fhir-server.s3.amazonaws.com/openapi/Condition.yml", name: "Condition"},
          {url: "https://iris-fhir-server.s3.amazonaws.com/openapi/Medication.yml", name: "Medication"},
          {url: "https://iris-fhir-server.s3.amazonaws.com/openapi/Observation.yml", name: "Observation"}              
        ],
        "urls.primaryName": "Patient"
      })
      window.ui = ui
    }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```